# use PHP login info to access mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, content-management-system

I have built a custom CMS for updating my website. Normally what I do is, I mention database login info (like username-host-password) to a php file and include that file into all the php script files having database syntax. By doing this I access database through that specific database user.

What I am trying to do is to replace that particular database user with the logged in user. More clearly if user John is logged in to the CMS, he will access the database using the username john. And if user Doe is logged in, he will access the database using the username joe.

Main motive for this is to track the user who has updated a table in mysql database.

Can you guys please provide me with a concept of how to do this.

Thank You!

Comment: `CMS` means? Also have you granted access to each individual user to access your `DB`?

Comment: Content management system

Comment: A database for every user; I hope you don't have many users because that stands at being a lot of possible maintenance. You didn't mean "tables" by any chance, did you?

Comment: I only have two users as of now and they both have access to the database.

Comment: I am sorry... I meant tables

Comment: Then just set up conditional statements, using variables as DB or table names then. You could also use a `WHERE` clause. I.e.: `WHERE user='$id'`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please be a little more specific.

Comment: So you want to change the file you're including? or what? can you please explain a little more.

Comment: I want to change the syntax on that file so that it uses the logged in user's username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i can do it here. I have a php file that i use require_once in all my pages. It is called logs and has a function in it here:

```
require_once("db_connection.php");

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

function logIt($msg,$tablename="",$application="" )
{
    global $connection;
    $cleanedMsg = remove_single_quotes($msg);
    $userID = "0";
    if ( isset($_SESSION['USERID']))
    {
        $userID = $_SESSION['USERID'];
    }

    $postDate = addHoursToTime(0);
    $query = "insert into web_log_tab (message, userid, post_Date, app, tablename) values ('{$cleanedMsg}',{$userID},'{$postDate}','{$application}','{$tablename}')";
    odbc_exec($connection,$query);
}
```

then after every query that I call in my php, i just call the logIt fufnction and pass in the query, tablename, and application. In my case, multiple applications are accessing the database so this way I can filter out by application, user, and even tablename. I hope this makes a little more sense and is helpful. When the user is logging into my application via the login page, I am putting their username, userid, userlevel in their private session so I can access anytime and from anywhere in the application.

```
$webPassword = $row['password'];
if ( $webPassword == $hashedPassword)
{
    $_SESSION['USERID'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['FIRSTNAME'] = $row['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['USER_LEVEL'] = $row['user_level'];
    echo '{success:true,error:0,id:'.$row['id'].'}';
}
```

Of course you can store the users username and use that insead, I just prefer the id and I'll join whatever information that I need at a later date.

Comment: great...just what doctor ordered. Thank You.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I have been getting help from people here for a long time and never really contributed. Thought it would be a good day to start.

Comment: What do you need help with? sorry for the delay, its been a holiday weekend, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I always store the username/userid in their session and I keep a table in my database called logs. I log every query, the time, and the userid and username so I might have an entry that looks like this:
'select * from foo','1','mike','7/1/2014 1:45 pm'

it gets pretty large so I have to purge it every once in a while, but for most of these apps, just our techs are using the apps so its at most around 20 people so its not that bad. It also helps to troubleshoot when someone says your app did a boo-boo. You can go back and look at what they were doing and see what server queries were executed.

Comment: I believe this will be the next step. But I am now wondering how to give access to that specific logged in user to the database. I can only add one user to the db.php file which I am includin in all the php scripts.

Comment: not sure if that is necessary though. If your main motive is to see who is updating table, if you track all queries and then add a column for the table that is getting updated you will achieve that same goal.

Comment: yes, but the userid will be same all the time. As whoever updates a table through the CMS, they will only access it through the particular mentioned user. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you store the username/id in the session, then it will be unique that that user and when your app gets ready to execute the query, you can log the fact that user10(mike) is running this query on this table. You only need one database login for your app because you will be tracking the user by their unique session.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that? I am little confused.

Comment: Sure shoot me your email and I can send you some screenshots and examples of what I am referring to.

Comment: Thanks...here is my id priyajit@innovatrix.co.in

Comment: Give me a few and I'll put something together for you

Comment: please take you time. Thank You.